# C++ : Why My Program Stopped ? iterator

Tags: c++, macos, iterator

I wrote some code , i use iterator but i can run it in OSX without any problem but in windows i get stopped error , what should i do ? i attach photos
i try most of Compiler ( Dev C++ , Clion , Codeblock , VS 2012 , Cfree )

Windows Error :

[Stopped in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1o6Q.jpg)

OSX :

[Works Fine in OSX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctefi.jpg)

here is my code :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Token{
private:
  string word;
  int word_count;
  vector<int> lines;
public:

void setWord(const string &word) {
    Token::word = word;
}

void setWord_count(int word_count) {
    Token::word_count = word_count;
}

void setLines(const vector<int> &lines) {
    Token::lines = lines;
}

Token(const string &word, int word_count, const vector<int> &lines) :     word(word), word_count(word_count),lines(lines) { }
Token(){}
const vector<int> &getLines() const {
    return lines;
}

const string &getWord() const {
    return word;
}

int getWord_count() const {
    return word_count;
}
};

map<string,int> wordCount;
map<string,vector<int>> lineNumbersVector;
list<Token> Alphabets[26];

bool checkWord(std::string word){
bool state = false;
if(isalpha(word.at(0)) && isalpha(word.at(word.length()-1))){
    state = true;
}else{
    state = false;
}
return state;
}

int doSegment(string sentence)
{

std::stringstream ss(sentence);
std::string to;
int lineNumber = 0;
string words[100];
int index = 0;

while(std::getline(ss,to,'\n')){
    lineNumber++;
    std::stringstream stream(to);
    std::string word;
    while(std::getline(stream,word,' ')) {
        if(checkWord(word)){
            words[index] = word;
            index++;
            lineNumbersVector[word].push_back(lineNumber);
        }
    }

    for(auto const &ent1 : lineNumbersVector) {
        // ent1.first is the first key
        for(auto const &ent2 : ent1.second) {
            // ent2.first is the second key
            // ent2.second is the data
            //cout << ent2 << "-";
        }
        //cout << "\n";
    }
}

for (int i = 0;i<index;i++){
    if (wordCount.count(words[i])>0){
        wordCount[words[i]] = wordCount[words[i]] + 1;
    }else{
        wordCount[words[i]] = 1;
    }
}

std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = wordCount.begin();
while(it != wordCount.end())
{
    //std::cout<<it->first<<" :: "<<it->second<<std::endl;
    it++;
    Token token;
    switch (it->first.at(0)){
        case 'a':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[0].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'b':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[1].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'c':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[2].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'd':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[3].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'e':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[4].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'f':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[5].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'g':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[6].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'h':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[7].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'i':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[8].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'j':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[9].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'k':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[10].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'l':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[11].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'm':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[12].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'n':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[13].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'o':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[14].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'p':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[15].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'q':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[16].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'r':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[17].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 's':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[18].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 't':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[19].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'u':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[20].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'v':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[21].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'w':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[22].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'x':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[23].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'y':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[24].push_back(token);
            break;
        case 'z':
            token.setWord(it->first);
            token.setWord_count(it->second);
            token.setLines(lineNumbersVector.at(it->first));
            Alphabets[25].push_back(token);
            break;
    }
}
return 0;
}

Token getWord(list<Token> _list,string word){
std::vector<Token> v{ std::begin(_list), std::end(_list) };
Token foundWord;

cout << v[0].getWord();
my_list.end(), some_value);
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {

}
return foundWord;
}

void searchWord(string wordToSearch) {

cout << "Word:" << wordToSearch << "  Count:" << wordCount.at(wordToSearch)  << "\n";
cout << "lines: ";
for (int i = 0; i < lineNumbersVector.at(wordToSearch).size(); ++i) {
    cout << lineNumbersVector.at(wordToSearch)[i] << ",";
}
}

int main() {

std::ifstream ifs("C:\program.txt");
std::string content( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ),
                         (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );

doSegment(content);


searchWord("Hi");

}
```

what should i do ? Thanks a lot

Comment: "what should i do ?" - debug your code. It likely has undefined behavior.

Comment: a) please write the error message here instead of linking an image. b) I dont believe that you tried most compilers (the programs you list are IDEs not compilers)

Comment: I recommend using different names between parameters and members.  One convention is to prefix member names with "m_" another convention is to add a suffix of "_" to member names.

Comment: Consider replacing your `switch` statement with a math expression.  The only statement that changes is `Alphabets[x].push_back(token);`, where `x` is a number from 0 to 25.  The math expression for `x` is `(it->first.at(0) - 'a')`. Of course, you will need to validate that the character is within the range of 'a' to 'z', before you apply the math expression.

Comment: Prefer to pass large structures, such as token lists and strings, by either constant reference (if they are not changed) or by reference (if they are modified).

Comment: Your code is not compiling for me.  Here are some of the issues: 1) `conio.h` is not a standard include file. 2) `map<string,vector<int>>` should have a space between `>>` to differentiate a closing `>` from the `>>` operator.  3) in function `getWord`, the expression `my_list.end(), some_value);` is incorrect syntax.  I am using G++ on Cygwin on Windows.

Comment: Your `getWord` function seems to be missing a bit.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews : hi , i think it doesn't reach the point of switch case

Answer (score 0):

Your typical windows input file `"C:\program.txt"` will first create a warning: `warning: unknown escape sequence: '\p'` if not disabled and then be interpreted as `"C:program.txt"`. You shall escape the backslash. That is one of the typical windows problems using backslash in paths. The original CPM were DOS has been copied from was using `/`. It is one of the mysteries of Microsoft why this has been changed to backslash.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile `my_list.end(), some_value );` is using undeclared 'my_list' and closing a bracket ')' that was not opened. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).